# R studio for Ubuntu 20.01

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio

I was going to download R studio for my project, however, I could not find the right version (For Ubuntu 20.01) in their [official website](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download)

If I download the version that was for Ubuntu 18, then is it compatible in Ubuntu 20.01?
If not what are the other ways I can do?

Comment: Yes, it is compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official website](http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/), here is the list of the supported Ubuntu releases:

- Hirsute Hippo (21.04, amd64 only)
- Groovy Gorilla (20.10, amd64 only),
- Focal Fossa (20.04; LTS and amd64 only),
- Bionic Beaver (18.04; LTS), and
- Xenial Xerus (16.04; LTS).

The installation instruction:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends software-properties-common dirmngr
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/"
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends r-base
```